# Process form using jquery, without php/rails

Tags: jquery, html, forms

My HTML:

```
    <div class = "submission_box">
    <form id="d_submit">
        <h3>D's: </h3>
            D 1: <input type="text" name="d1">  <br />
            D 2: <input type="text" name="d2">  <br />
            D 3: <input type="text" name="d3">  <br />
            D 4: <input type="text" name="d4">  <br />
        <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#d_submit").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'html',
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/gwsearch/ajax_search?d1='+d1+'&d2='+d2,
          crossDomain: true,
          success:function(result){

        $("#box").html(result);
      }});

   });
});
```

I'm wondering why I can't somehow read the parameters d1, d2, d3, or d4 without using php or some other type of platform like that.  Is there anyway I can read these from my jQuery code without posting to php?  If not, what is the simplest/most universal way to go about posting these parameters to my jQuery code?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand... Can't you just read the values before you make them part of the url you're posting? `alert(d1)`

Comment: @KevinB no, i haven't gotten that far yet.  console gives me an error saying d1 is undefined

Comment: So, what you're really asking is, "How do i get the value of an input?" right?

Comment: @KevinB you're right in assuming that the url I'm posting to already is setup, within ajax. I just need to somehow get parameters in an html form, to pass to this javascript, so that i may call the respective method on the remote host.

Comment: @KevinB yes, how do i get the value of an input to be recognized in my jquery code

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="d1" id="d1">
```

Add the ID for easy referencing.

```
d1_val = $("#d1").val();
```

This will store the value of the form input to the variable

Comment: so with this solution, i really don't even need to submit the form..correct?  just trigger the jquery and read the value of the textbox..?